# Why is my grid border wrapping around the button?

Tags: css, button, css-grid

I am trying to get a horizontal line as a divider between each tour date, so I used a grid border to create this effect, as using

---

in the grid setting was not working out. However, when it comes to the buttons, the border seems to wrap around the button element instead of on the actual grid border like the rest of the grid.

[Grid border wrapping around button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Vul.jpg)

I'm a beginner coder so I'm having a hard time figuring out why this is happening and how to fix it.

Here is the way my CSS is set up.

```
.tour-dates {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
  grid-template-rows: 7fr;
  align-items: end;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-left: 6.5rem;
  margin-right: 6.5rem;
}

.tix {
  grid-column: 4/5;
  align-self: start;
  justify-self: end;
}

.rsvp {
  grid-column: 5/6;
  align-self: start;
  justify-self: end;
}

.gig-0 {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  border-bottom: #000 solid 1px;
} 
  >! this is repeated for all rows

  button.tix {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

button.rsvp {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: So, just to clarify, please edit your question to include the relevant HTML as well as the CSS. Creating a stack snippet which demonstrates the problem is desirable, but not mandatory.